# How do I make a parent child relationship list in C#?

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Parent
{
    private int Id;
    private String Title;
    private int? Parent;
}
```

And the following objects:

```
id:1,title:"Europe",parent:null  
id:2,title:"Western Europe",parent:1  
id:3,title:"Eastern Europe",parent:1  
id:5,title:"Germany",parent:2
```

I'd like to create a parentlist string from titles by id

> `getallparent(5)` will return `Europe,Western Europe` and `getparent(3)` will return `Europe`

How do I do that in C#?

This is a countrylist: all country and region have an id, title and a parent
id 1 is Europe without parent, id 3 is Western Europe with parent 1, id 5 is Germany with parent 3
So i would like to give an id,

> `in my example 5, which should return Europe, Western Europe`

Comment: Your objects are composed by the ID of other objects? It seems like you're trying to model your domain objects as if this was a relational database.

Comment: I have a List<Parent> parentlist which im trying iterate throught,
while(p.parent != null)

Comment: Your `p.parent` is an Nullable<int>.  Try making it a Parent, so that it is a reference to another Parent object (search for linked-lists here in SO).   Or you could use the List<T>.Find method to search by Parent.Id as in `_allParents.Find(p => { return this.Id == p.Id; });`, which assumes your list is called `allParents` and is a static field of the Parent class.

Comment: Can you give me a code example?

Comment: I don't understand your inputs and outputs. Why would `getParent(3)` return `a` and `b`? parent "3" is id:3, title:d, so I'd expect it to return that one.  You have most of the criteria we need for a question to be open, what you're missing is that your inputs and outputs make no sense. You need to explain what get Parent takes in, and what and what you expect to come out, and why.

Comment: this is a countrylist
all country and region have an id, title and a parent  
eg. id 1 is Europe without parent, id 3 is Western Europe with parent 1, id 5 is Germany with parent 3

So i would like to give an id in my example 5, which should return Europe, Western Europe

Comment: @SzabolcsSzrenko You should edit that into your question.

Comment: updated description, sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include a collection of all of the Parent objects that are created then you can use this list to search for those that match the criteria you need and compile a sub-set that matches your requirements.  This can then be used to format the output string you require.

```
    public class Parent
{
    private int Id;
    private String Title;
    private int? Parent;

    // Private static fields for managing Ids and the list of all instances
    private static List<Parent> _allParents = new List<Parent>();
    private static int _nextId = 0;

    // Default constructor
    public Parent()
    {
        // Set default field values.
        this.Id = _nextId++;
        this.Title = "";
        this.Parent = null;

        // Store the new object in the static collection.
        _allParents.Add(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a list of Parent objects whose Ids have corresponding Parent objects.
    /// NOTE: This method returns a List that includes the Parent object with the Id
    /// passed in.  This will be the first item in the List and should be skipped if
    /// only higher level relationships are required.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Id">Nullable<int> Id of the item whose parents are to be found.</param>
    /// <returns>List<Parent> of the Parents objects</returns>
    public List<Parent> ListParents(int? Id)
    {
        List<Parent> parents = new List<Parent>();
        // Id values that are null mark the end of the ancestor chain
        while (Id.HasValue)
        {
            // Find the Parent with the requested Id
            var parent = _allParents.Find(p => { return this.Id == p.Id; });
            // null means no Parent object with the requested Id exists
            if (null != parent)
            {
                // Add the Parent and its parents.
                parents.Add(parent);
                // Check for the next Id
                Id = parent.Id;
            }
        }
        return parents;
    }

    public String GetAllParents(int? Id)
    {
        StringBuilder allParents = new StringBuilder();

        // Find all the parents
        List<Parent> parents = ListParents(Id);

        // Add the Title of each parent in the list to the result
        for(int n = 0; n < parents.Count; n++)
        {
            allParents.Append(parents[n].Title);

            // Seperate all but the last parent with commas
            if(n < (parents.Count - 1))
                allParents.Append(", ");
        }

        return allParents.ToString();
    }
}
```

As pointed out in some of the comments, using a relational database style ID makes this implementation more complicated than necessary.  Replacing it with a reference to an existing object, creating a standard linked list could simplify the solution.